# SQL - Compare rows based on date and transpose difference

Tags: sql, oracle

Scenario:

Table **'HIST'**

| RID | VALUE | HIST_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | V111 | 2019-01-01 |
| 1 | V112 | 2020-02-11 |
| 1 | V112 | 2020-03-08 |
| **1** | **V113** | **2020-04-11** |
| **1** | **V114** | **2021-03-15** |
| 2 | V211 | 2020-04-11 |
| 2 | V211 | 2021-03-16 |
| 3 | V311 | 2019-05-01 |
| 3 | V312 | 2020-01-01 |

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

| RID | VALUE_OLD | VALUE_NEW |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | V113 | V114 |

I want to display difference between rows in column 'VALUE'  grouping by RID where the HIST_DATE is between **'2020-03-31'** and **'2021-04-01'**

Then transpose the different values in Column 'VALUE_OLD' AND 'VALUE_NEW'.

Note : Assuming only 2 different values can occur between those dates

**Oracle SQL**

Comment: Please explain the logic.  What happened to the rest of the values in the table?

Comment: I only want to know difference in values between 2 checkpoints of time. The rest difference is not needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use LAG/LEAD analytics functions :

- LAG returns value from a previous row in the table.
- LEAD returns value from the next row in the table.

```
select rid
    , LAG(hist_date) OVER(partition by rid order by hist_date ) as HIST_DATE_OLD 
    , hist_date  as HIST_DATE
    , LAG(value) OVER(partition by rid order by hist_date ) as VALUE_OLD 
    , value as VALUE_NEW
from hist
```

```
select rid
    , lead(hist_date) OVER(partition by rid order by hist_date desc) as HIST_DATE_OLD 
    , hist_date  as HIST_DATE
    , lead(value) OVER(partition by rid order by hist_date desc) as VALUE_OLD 
    , value as VALUE_NEW
from hist
order by rid, hist_date
```

Then you can filter and format following your needs

```
select rid, VALUE_OLD, VALUE_NEW from (
    select rid
       , TO_CHAR(lead(hist_date) OVER(partition by rid order by hist_date desc), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as HIST_DATE_OLD 
       , TO_CHAR(hist_date , 'YYYY-MM-DD') as HIST_DATE
       , lead(value) OVER(partition by rid order by hist_date desc) as VALUE_OLD 
       , value as VALUE_NEW
    from hist
    where HIST_DATE between '2020-03-31' and '2021-04-01'
    and   rid = 1  
order by rid, hist_date
)
where HIST_DATE_OLD IS NOT NULL

RID VALUE_OLD VALUE_NEW 
--- --------- --------- 
  1 V113      V114
```

```
select * from (
    select rid
       , TO_CHAR(lead(hist_date) OVER(partition by rid order by hist_date desc), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as HIST_DATE_OLD 
       , TO_CHAR(hist_date , 'YYYY-MM-DD') as HIST_DATE
       , lead(value) OVER(partition by rid order by hist_date desc) as VALUE_OLD 
       , value as VALUE_NEW
    from hist
order by rid, hist_date
)
where HIST_DATE between '2020-03-31' and '2021-04-01'
    and   rid = 1  

RID HIST_DATE_OLD HIST_DATE  VALUE_OLD VALUE_NEW 
--- ------------- ---------- --------- --------- 
  1 2020-03-08    2020-04-11 V112      V113      
  1 2020-04-11    2021-03-15 V113      V114
```

take care about the filter inside and outside the main SELECT

- outside, you are filtering after doing the LAG/LEAD operation (above)
- inside, you are filtering before doing the LAG/LEAD operation (below)

```
RID HIST_DATE_OLD HIST_DATE  VALUE_OLD VALUE_NEW 
--- ------------- ---------- --------- --------- 
  1               2020-04-11           V113      
  1 2020-04-11    2021-03-15 V113      V114
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only 2 different values can occur between those dates

```
 select distinct RID, 
        first_value(VALUE) over(order by HIST_DATE) VALUE_OLD,
        first_value(VALUE) over(order by HIST_DATE desc) VALUE_NEW
 from HIST
 where HIST_DATE between  date '2020-03-31' and date '2021-04-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to:

1. Find last hist_date for each rid (newvals)
2. Find last hist_date for each rid (oldvals) that is previous to the very last (newvals)
3. Read hist table to find new val for each rid
4. Read hist table to find previous val for each rid

You are always showing the two last values of each rid, no matter if there are other older values.

```
SELECT
    n.rid,
    o.value AS value_old,
    n.value AS value_new
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            rid,
            MAX(hist_date) AS DATE
        FROM
            hist
        GROUP BY
            rid
    )
    newvals,
    (
        SELECT
            hist.rid,
            MAX(hist_date) AS DATE
        FROM
            hist,
            (
                SELECT
                    rid,
                    MAX(hist_date) AS DATE
                FROM
                    hist
                GROUP BY
                    rid
            )
            newvals
        WHERE
            hist.rid=newvals.rid
        AND hist.hist_date<newvals.date
        GROUP BY
            hist.rid
    )
    oldvals,
    hist n,
    hist o
WHERE
    n.rid=o.rid
and n.rid=newvals.rid
and n.rid=oldvals.rid
AND n.hist_date=newvals.date
AND o.hist_date=oldvals.date
```